# Pulsating Social Media Buttons in CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

So i've created these pulsating social media buttons using CSS.
After a couple of pulsations you can see that there's a **small red line** on the right hand side of the instagram-icon. Any idea on what's causing this and how to remove it?

https://jsfiddle.net/pm9hkyy8/2/

Snippet:

```
@keyframes pulser {
  from {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  to {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
}
#footer a {
        color: #999;
        color: rgba(185, 186, 187, 0.5);
        animation-name: pulser;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

/* Stopping the pulsation on hover for that particular child */
a:hover {
  color: #bbb;
  color: #b9babb;
  animation-name: pulser;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Also, feel free to use this code and improve on it :)

screenshot: http://puu.sh/qJBkj/d3701d834e.png

Comment: not see this bug. firefox 48

Comment: Not really seeing it in Chrome either... but you may want to add `outline: none;` to the anchor css. It, combined with `text-decoration`, eliminates default browser styling of hover events. Some browser outline as well as decorate. Nice pulse by the way.

Comment: where used red color in u css?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov I haven't that's what's so weird.

Comment: @Scott you gotta look closely. I'm using the latest chrome build.Here's a screenshot: http://puu.sh/qJBkj/d3701d834e.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove below CSS which is empty and causing that line

```
            #footer .actions li a:before {

            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/pm9hkyy8/4/

Comment: yes @Joel, after removing that... it is not showing up ,as there is nothing wrong or extra css which is causing that